# React-hook-form Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms, react-hook-form

Apologies in advanced, I am really struggling with React-hook-forms, any help is much appreciated.

I've managed to get my form fields prepopulated from a database, but my problem arises when trying to use custom inputs.

I have a Checkbox component like so:

```
  import React from "react";

const Checkbox = React.forwardRef(
  (
    {
      label,
      name,
      value,
      onChange,
      defaultChecked,
      onBlur,
      type,
      ...rest
    }: any,
    forwardedRef: any
  ) => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(defaultChecked);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (onChange) {
        onChange(checked);
      }
    }, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
    }, [checked]);


    return (
      <div onClick={() => setChecked(!checked)} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
        <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={value}
          name={name}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          ref={forwardedRef}
          checked={checked}
          {...rest}
        />
        [{checked ? "X" : " "}]{label}
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default Checkbox;
```

Which gets default values and applies them to the component:

```
import "./styles.css";
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const defaultValues = {
  gender: "male"
};

export default function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm({
    defaultValues: defaultValues
  });

  const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
    console.log(data, "data");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Checkbox
        {...register("gender")}
        name={"gender"}
        value={"boy"}
        label={"Boy"}
        // when this added, the custom checks work but everything is checked
        // defaultChecked={defaultValues}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

But when I call the onChange function I get the following error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')
```

The behavior is working as expected when just clicking on the checkboxes, and the default state is loaded for the native inputs, but it doesn't reflect the custom checkbox UI without user interaction.

[Here's a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-pare-30zysb?file=/src/App.tsx:0-664) showing my issue.

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Why are you calling `onChange` in your effect hook? I imagine it expects an `Event` argument but you are only passing it `defaultChecked`

Comment: Hey Phil thanks for your response. I'll be honest I've been stuck on this for days, my code is based on this Codesandbox here which uses v5 not v7 (it's the only example I've been able to find which shows how to use defaultChecked): https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-custom-checkbox-forked-pi9of2?file=/src/App.js:501-751 If you know of any other examples I'd appreciate that... I've read the documentation but it hasn't helped me so far

Comment: Looking at [the docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/), the checkbox type is usually used to register an array value. Is that what you want? If you're after a single selection from a bunch of options, I'd go with a radio (or `<select>`)

Comment: Yeah mate it's an array that I'm after. My real code includes a checkboxes which bind to single arrays, e.g styles: ['dresses', 'shorts'] if that makes sense

Comment: Did you realise your sandbox is only rendering `<Checkbox>` in `index.tsx`?

Comment: If you set your checkbox value to `"male"` to match the default value registered in `useForm`, it should show as checked

Comment: Hey Phil, I've updated the Sandbox with two values, and changed the checkbox value as you suggested (my bad, getting tired lol). Anyway, it shows the default value correctly for the native checkbox, but sadly not with the custom checkbox

Comment: Works fine here with all the extra stuff taken out ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-lake-xs7udd?file=/src/App.tsx. If you want controlled components (ie be able to change the values outside the direct form elements), you'll need to use `useController` and `Controller`. Scroll down to the _Tips_ section on this page ~ https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/

Comment: Ok thanks mate I'll take a look tomorrow, brain dead now but I think that useController and Controller is what I'm after. Thank you and have a great evening / morning wherever you are!